# unable to fetch django filtered objects uniquely while slicing the queryset

Tags: python, json, django

I am working on item display page of an e commerce site. So suppose the site has 10 items, now I need to fetch 2 items each time and we need to fetch the item using the last_index and last_price of the 2nd element fetched before. So the JSON to fetch the record is like this

```
{
    "last_price": 6000,
    "last_index": 12
}
```

So when the item list page opens up the very first time the JSON goes something like this

```
{
    "last_price": 6000,
    "last_index": 0
}
```

and at django end I am firing this query.

```
if params['last_index'] == 0:
            item_list = queryset.order_by('-price_val').filter(price_val__lte=params['last_price'])[:2]
elif params['last_index'] > 0:
            item_list = queryset.order_by('-price_val').filter(price_val__lte=params['last_price']).filter(~Q(pk=params['last_index']))[:2]
```

Now the 10 items have the following price

```
{0:100, 1:200, 2:300, 3:400, 4:900, 5:1200, 6:300,7:100, 8:500 9:200 }
```

Now when django orders the element it orders 
[5,4,8,3,6,2,9,1,7,0]

and fetches the item in two slices when API is reached at the very first time

```
[5,4]
[8,3]
[6,2]
[9,1]
[7,0]
```

Now when it reaches the 3rd set it just replicates those values only as it finds the `last_price` same so it replicates record . I am not able to find any source to overcome this, If anyone has done that before please let me know.

Comment: When you say 'set' do you mean this is in a loop?

Comment: @Ringil yes I mean items per iteration

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking you need to order by both and filter on both:

```
item_list = queryset\
    .order_by('-price_val', 'pk')\
    .filter(
        Q(price_val__lt=params['last_price']) |
        Q(price_val=params['last_price'], pk__gt=params['last_index'])
    )[:2]
```

Comment: Thanks Anentropic , but it does not solve my problem , suppose element with id=20 has value 200 and id=3 has value 1000 then it would not fetch record 3 as we have moved ahead with `pk__gt=params['last_index']`